# What's the quickest validation query from a jdbc-pool to a specific table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, validation, connection-pooling

I usually use `SELECT 1` as my preferred validation-query from tomcat jdbc pools, because it returns only one row with the result **1** that is very faster, but today I've found one terrible mistake:

My database **only** has **one table** with its **primary key** and is **not nullable**. This table sometimes is dropped, and then appears again by application circumstances. And that's the problem, `SELECT 1` validate connection to database because it's already up but the table is missing so  I get a terrible exception.

So, the solutions passes by finding one validation-query against the only table that exists in the database. And also, I need the query to be as fast as possible, because the performance in the application is one of the main objetives.

You can answer than an obvius query may be `SELECT 1 FROM THE_TABLE` but this query returns **1** for each row that the table has, and that's not very quick.

So, **what could be the faster validation-query to this table??**

*EDIT*

If I need to return *at least one result*, **How should be the validation-query?**
I ask this because some pool implementations, like commons-dbcp doesn't accept a query without results as a validated query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this, which should validate the table exists without actually loading any data by pulling `0` rows and no actual columns.

```
SELECT TOP 0 1 FROM THE_TABLE
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c670b/3

---

There are also built-in ways to check for the existance of objects in SQL SERVER.  Here are two examples that do effectively the same thing.

```
select count(1) from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'THE_TABLE'
select OBJECT_ID('THE_TABLE') is not null
```

Comment: If you look at the execution plan which is attached in the demo, it shows a [`constant scan`](http://www.scarydba.com/2008/07/01/constant-scan-in-execution-plans/), which effectively costs nothing.

Comment: Do you know how to return one result in the validation-query?

Comment: The two examples I provided in the addendum would return one result.  First one would return 1 = exists, 0 = not exists.  Second one would return TRUE = exists, FALSE = not exists (actually I think that would be 1/0 as well in SQL Server)

Comment: I will test them tomorrow. Thanks again